# users treeview structure with level details

Tags: php, codeigniter, binary-tree

i am trying to create tree view structure of users, each user will have 2children nodes, my code creates tree view perfectly, but i stuck on getting level information.

```
 public function treeView() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $leftArray=array('viewMode'=>'admin',"isLogin"=>$this->session->userdata('isUserLogin'));
        $this->load->view('left',$leftArray);

        $alias="*";
        $table="user";
        $where=array("userId"=>$this->session->userdata('userId'));
        $userDetails= $this->commonmodel->getData($alias,$table,$where);

        $this->getTreeArray($userDetails[0]->userId,  $this->stageCounter);
        $treeArray = json_encode($this->globTreeArray);
        //echo $this->stageCounter;exit;
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($this->globTreeArray);
        //exit;
        $treeviewArray=array("treeArray"=>$treeArray,"userDetails"=>$userDetails[0]);
        $this->load->view('treeView',$treeviewArray);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }     

public function getTreeArray($userId,$level) {

        $childArray=array();
        $alias="*";
        $table="user_relationship";
        $where=array("placementUserId"=>$userId);
        $childRecords= $this->commonmodel->getData($alias,$table,$where);
        foreach ($childRecords as $child){

            $temp=array();
            if($child->placementSide=='left'){
                $childUserDetails=$this->getUserDetails($child->childUserId);
                $temp[]="<div><img src='".  base_url()."assets/img/default-avatar.png' width='80'/></div>".$childUserDetails->registrationCode."</br>".$childUserDetails->fullName;
                $placementUserDetails=$this->getUserDetails($child->placementUserId);
                $temp[]="<div><img src='".  base_url()."assets/img/default-avatar.png' width='80'/></div>".$placementUserDetails->registrationCode."</br>".$placementUserDetails->fullName;
                $temp[]=(string)$this->stageCounter;
                $childArray[0]=$temp;
                $this->globTreeArray[]=$temp;
            }
            if($child->placementSide=='right'){
                $childUserDetails=$this->getUserDetails($child->childUserId);
                $temp[]="<div><img src='".  base_url()."assets/img/default-avatar.png' width='80'/></div>".$childUserDetails->registrationCode."</br>".$childUserDetails->fullName;
                $placementUserDetails=$this->getUserDetails($child->placementUserId);
                $temp[]="<div><img src='".  base_url()."assets/img/default-avatar.png' width='80'/></div>".$placementUserDetails->registrationCode."</br>".$placementUserDetails->fullName;
                $temp[]=(string)$this->stageCounter;
                $childArray[1]=$temp;
                $this->globTreeArray[]=$temp;
            }
            //if($level<=2)
            //{
                    //echo $level."------".$childUserDetails->registrationCode."----------".$placementUserDetails->registrationCode."<br>";
                    if($this->hasChildren($childUserDetails->userId)==TRUE)
                    {
                        $this->stageCounter++;
                        $this->getTreeArray($childUserDetails->userId,$this->stageCounter);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->stageCounter--;
                    }
            //}
        }
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($this->globTreeArray);
        //exit;
        return json_encode($this->globTreeArray);
    }
```

as my code shows i need three elements in on 0 position child, on 1 position parent and on 2 position level number,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by  following  below steps:

1. Take one global array  say `$Leveldata = array()`.
2. Each time you call the function has child,  if you found child push that data in to array.
3. Once you got your counter with level number you want ,say 3,
   break your loop.